# Column count doesn't match value count at row with Auto Increment set

Tags: mysql

Created a table using the following SQL statement in phpmyadmin.

```
CREATE TABLE User (
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
name VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=utf8;
```

When I try to do a insert using the following insert statement I get the error "#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

```
INSERT INTO User (user_id, name) VALUES ('Taliesin');
```

I made the user_id a primary key in phpmyadmin but I still get this error. Shouldn't the user_id be auto inserted when the column is set to AUTO INCREMENT? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to specify two columns since one is auto incremented

```
INSERT INTO User(name) VALUES('Taliesin')
```

Comment: Thank you. I was also looking over the docs I see I can omit it.